# im trying to make a program that ask the user to enter a question and answer, but the program does not loop right

Tags: c++, file, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a project where I ask the user to create a question and answer. the program then will ask the user if they were to add more questions. For some reason, my program doesn't loop. here's my code. if there are any suggestion please let me know. thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string exam_Name;
    string questions, DMV, answer;
    fstream examfile;
    string another_question,no,yes;

    examfile.open("exam.txt");
    // ask the user to create a question

    while (another_question != "no");
    {
        cout << "create a question. " << endl;
        getline(cin, questions);
        cout << "enter the answer" << endl;
        getline(cin, answer);
        // program will now ask the user to create another question
        cout << "would you like to add another question, yes or no ?" << endl;
        getline(cin, another_question);
    }

    //display question and answer on the document
    examfile << questions << endl;
    examfile << answer;

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What does "does not loop right" mean? What is the actual input you fed to your program and what was output?

Comment: Use your debugger to check the contents of 'another_question' when it gets evaluated. I bet it isn't what you think it is. Are you familiar with the newline character?

Comment: Remove semicolon `;` in string with `while`

Comment: I want my program to ask the user to enter questions and answers. Also, those questions and answers would be save in a text file. When I run my program, it only show the most recent question. I want to show all questions when the user inputs those questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** I added whole code.

---

`;` just after `while` statement should be removed. That is, since

```
while (another_question != "no");
```

is infinite loop and never end, we should rewrite this line as follows:

```
while (another_question != "no")
```

---

> I want to show all questions

Putting `examfile <<` in the `while{...}` section, you can show all questions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string questions, answer;
    fstream examfile;
    string another_question;

    examfile.open("exam.txt");
    // ask the user to create a question

    while (another_question != "no");
    {
        cout << "create a question. " << endl;
        getline(cin, questions);
        cout << "enter the answer" << endl;
        getline(cin, answer);

        //display question and answer on the document
        examfile << questions << endl;
        examfile << answer << endl;

        // program will now ask the user to create another question
        cout << "would you like to add another question, yes or no ?" << endl;
        getline(cin, another_question);
    }

    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are attempting to concatenate questions and answers into individual strings will not work, they will be overwritten by calling getline().

```
while (another_question != "no");
```

The above line is considered poor practice, you should use a more fitting type as the loop condition as well as do away with the semicolon.

Here is an example of code that is much better and will yield the results you desire.

```
    // You want to append any changes to the file, for example
    // in the case of re-using the program.
    File.open( "exam.txt", std::ios::app );

    while( AnotherQuestion ) {
        printf( "Please enter a question:\n" );
        std::getline( std::cin, Buffer );
        File << Buffer << std::endl;

        printf( "Please enter an answer:\n" );
        std::getline( std::cin, Buffer );
        File << Buffer << std::endl;

        printf( "Would you like to add another question? (Yes/No)\n" );
        std::getline( std::cin, Buffer );

        // You want to be able to receive input regardless of case.
        std::transform( Buffer.begin( ), Buffer.end( ), Buffer.begin( ), ::tolower );
        AnotherQuestion = Buffer.find( "yes" ) != std::string::npos;
    }
```

Another approach you could take is to create a class that contains questions and answers, then store input data into a std::vector which would be written to the file at the end. Just something to think about :-)